# Can C# store more precise data than doubles?

Tags: c#, types, double, precision

`double` in C# don't hold enough precision for my needs. I am writing a fractal program, and after zooming in a few times I run out of precision.

I there a data type that can hold more precise floating-point information (i.e more decimal places) than a double?

Comment: If you want to display fractals, zooming should be possible infinitely. You might want to search for an algorithm that returns your values depending on zoom level.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) is designed for just that.

However, do be aware that the range of the decimal type is smaller than a double. That is double can hold a larger value, but it does so by losing precision. Or, as stated on MSDN:

> The decimal keyword denotes a 128-bit
>   data type. Compared to floating-point
>   types, the decimal type has a greater
>   precision and a smaller range, which
>   makes it suitable for financial and
>   monetary calculations. The approximate
>   range and precision for the decimal
>   type are shown in the following table.

The primary difference between `decimal` and `double` is that [`decimal` is fixed-point and `double` is floating point](http://floating-point-gui.de/). That means that decimal stores an exact value, while `double` represents a value represented by a fraction, and is less precise. A `decimal`is 128 bits, so it takes the double space to store. Calculations on `decimal` is also slower (measure !).

If you need even larger precision, then `BigInteger` can be used from .NET 4. (You will need to handle decimal points yourself). Here you should be aware, that BigInteger is immutable, so any arithmetic operation on it will create a new instance - if numbers are large, this might be crippling for performance.

I suggest you look into exactly how precise you need to be. Perhaps your algorithm can work with normalized values, that can be smaller ? If performance is an issue, one of the built in floating point types are likely to be faster.

Comment: Integer, double, float, decimal are all immutable too and arithmetic operations create new instances...so that's a red herring.  Decimal and BigInteger are slow because they aren't just simple hardware primitives.

Comment: Well, all right, it's not totally a red herring because they can grow arbitrarily large in contrast to the other fixed-size numeric types, but if that's the case the value wouldn't fit in other types anyway.

Comment: `Decimal` is a floating-point type, even though its dynamic range is less than that of `float`.  I find the design curious, given that the type takes 16 bytes, and a type with a 68-bit whole-number part and 60-bit fraction could have done almost everything `Decimal` does more efficiently.  Not quite as much range on the high end nor precision on the low end, but capable of guaranteeing that addition and subtraction will either be performed with perfect precision or else fail entirely--a guarantee not provided by `double`.

Answer (score 5):

The .NET Framework 4 introduces the System.Numerics.BigInteger struct that can hold numbers with an arbitrary large precision.

Comment: But be aware that doing arithmetic operations on BigInteger might be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) (.NET 4) if you need even more precision than `Decimal` gives you.

Comment: `BigInteger` (like `int`) can only store integral numbers.

Comment: Yes but it's often quite easy to modify the fractal algorithms to work with integers or to fake BigInteger as a fixed point decimal.