# c# Convert String to double loss of precision

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
string value = "9223372036854775807";
double parsedVal = double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

... and the result is `9.2233720368547758E+18` which is not the exact same number. How should I convert string to double without loss of precision?

Comment: Try `System.Convert.ToDouble`

Comment: The answer is: use a shorter string. Doubles don't have infinite precision; the largest odd number you can store in a double is only 16 digits long. Or, perhaps more realistic, convert to an ulong instead of a double.

Comment: @xbonez - havent' cehcked in a while but pretty sure that is just a shortcut for the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't convert 9223372036854775807 to [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) without loss of precision, due to the definition of a double (([IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)) standard for binary floating-point arithmetic).

> By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision,
>   although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

Answer (score 8):

`double` can only guarantee 16 (approx) decimal digits of accuracy. You might try switching to `decimal` (which has a few more bits to play with, and holds that value with plenty of headroom).

Comment: By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.

Comment: @Mitch ultimately it is limited by the very definition of IEEE 754, though

Comment: But why? I expect to be able to parse any double from double.MinValue to double.MaxValue. If we have value for 9223372036854775807 why I can't get it from string? It's ok if it's not in the exponential notation.

Comment: @marc: since that is what a double complies with, yes.

Comment: @user yes, but it only has given fidelity *within* that range; it has a limited precision, as defined by IEEE 754. It will parse it to the closest value it can represent.

Comment: You just can't store 9223372036854775807 in a double. A double isn't precise enough. You can store _approximately_ 9223372036854775807 in a double, but if that isn't good enough, use something with more precision.

Answer (score 1):

Using Decimal will get you the precision you need here. However please note that Decimal will not have the same storage **range** as a double.

See [Can C# store more precise data than doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473136/can-c-sharp-store-more-precise-data-than-doubles)

Comment: Re "storage capacity" - a `decimal` actually has *more* than a `double` - the representation is different, but it is a 96-bit number