# How can I make Visual Studio find only single slashes and not double slashes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

To add more precision to floating point numbers, I have to go through a bunch of C# classes and, wherever there is a division operation, multiply both the numerator and denominator by 1000. So suppose we have a numerator, n and a denominator, d. Then the original would look like this: n / d. And I would need to change it to (n*1000)/(d*1000).

To search for all the division operators I'm using the find function (ctrl+f) in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. I'm searching for all '/'. The problem is that the find function also picks up the slashes in the comments. How can have the find function only find the single slash '/' and not the double slash '//'?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: have you tried a regular expression?

Comment: No. How would I write the regular expression?

Comment: give it a try. if you have problems, report back.

Comment: As a side comment, you know what `(n * 1000) / (d * 1000) = n / d` ? So you don't change anything.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it adds more precision to the final calculation.

Comment: I still insist on *anything*.

Comment: What about ctrl-f and look for <space>/<space>. Does that find what you are looking for?

Comment: Use a [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx)?

Comment: <space>/<space> would work for some, but sometimes the programmer did not include a space.

Comment: We are using doubles.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473136/can-c-sharp-store-more-precise-data-than-doubles (I hope I'm being helpful)

Comment: BTW, I don't believe this will change the precision in any way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Good

Regex find (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> with the *Use Regular Expressions* option checked) `[^/<]/[^/>]` in your solution - basically a `/` that:

- is not preceded by another `/` or a `<` (i.e. closing XML comment tags like `</para>`)
- is not followed by another `/` or a `>` (i.e. standalone XML comment tags like `<see cref="Foo"/>`)

The only false positives I see with this approach in a quick check against a solution of ~80 projects are...

- Dates (e.g. `1/1/2014`)
- `/` in comments (e.g. `Note that an up/down change....`)

...but others could come up depending on your code base - for example:

- URLs (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/users/1810429/j0e3gan`)
- XPaths (e.g. `/Customer/Address/City/text()`)

### Better

*If* you consistently put spaces between the division operator and its operands, you could tighten the regex a bit to alleviate these false positives, changing it from...

```
[^/<]/[^/>]
```

...to...

```
[^/<] +/ +[^/>]
```

...where `+` will match one or more spaces of course.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex expression:

> [^/<]/[^/>]

"Not a slash followed by a slash followed by not a slash"

Comment: This is okay...but also matches closing and standalone tags in XML comments.

Comment: Updated to exclude </ and />

Answer (score 2):

You can find single `/` in VS2013 with the following using :

- type `Ctrl`+`f`
- in the search box, type `(?<!/)/(?!/)`
- under the search box, click on the icon representing `.*`
- select `Entire Solution`
- Launch the search

But, you must know that the result will be not what you really want, because, you will find XAML code, URL, ...

Comment: Yes it will find xaml code, but at least it doesn't pick up the comments. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression search for `(?<!/)/(?!/)` should find only single slashes, by using zero-width negative lookbehind/lookahead assertions.  The `.*` button in the small find dialog turns on regular expression searches.  There is a checkbox under "Find options" for the full search dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F).

Comment: This just dresses up @mclaassen's so-so regex with a negative lookbehind & lookahead - same so-so results and needlessly complicated by a negative lookbehind & lookahead.

Comment: @J0e3gan Well, in my defense, I answered first, and not being psychic I wasn't to know that I wasn't adding anything to the (non-existent) previous answers.  While I am happy to be corrected, you may want to work on your delivery.