# Double type strange behavior while concatenating with String or Converting to String

Tags: c#, string, double, tostring, string-concatenation

I have logging functionality in project which compares objects value and displays differences but i have a scenarion i have latitude and longitude values in double data type but when i concatenate it with string or convert it to string i am getting strange behaviour as it is showing the same value in both variables which is totally not understandable how it is happening.

Here is the code:

```
double value1 = -6.2845230102539063;
double value2 = -6.2845230102539098;
        if (!object.Equals(value1, value2))
        {
            var result = value2 + " to " + value1;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

### Expected Output :

> > -6.2845230102539098 to -6.2845230102539063

### Actual Output :

> > -6.28452301025391 to -6.28452301025391

Here is **DEMO FIDDLE**:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/0XM3Da

What is happening here?

Comment: values are just getting round off may be due to the size limit of var!

Comment: yes it looks like precision issue but i am not sure because it supports 16-digit percision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Double has a precision of 15-16 digits. You've exceeded that limit.  **You should use Decimal instead.** See here for details: [Can C# store more precise data than doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473136/can-c-sharp-store-more-precise-data-than-doubles)

Comment: This answer is not completely accurate because `value1 != value2`

Answer (score 2):

This is addressed in @LukeH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658420/1220238) to "Formatting doubles for output in C#":

> The problem is that .NET will always round a `double` to 15 significant
>   decimal digits *before* applying your formatting, regardless of the
>   precision requested by your format and regardless of the exact decimal
>   value of the binary number.

Using the DoubleConverter class linked to in that answer, we get

```
var x = -6.2845230102539063;
var y = -6.2845230102539098;

Console.WriteLine(x == y);
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(x));
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(y));
```

which prints

```
False
-6.28452301025391
-6.28452301025391
-6.28452301025390625
-6.284523010253909802713678800500929355621337890625
```

Or you can use the G17 format specification

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("G17"));
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString("G17"));
```

which will give you

```
-6.2845230102539063
-6.2845230102539098
```

Answer (score 0):

From:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

'By default, the return value only contains 15 digits of precision although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally.'

So it knows that they are not the same size, but doesn't display them that way.

Comment: when i debug and inspect it shows correct but when concatenating it shows strange

Answer (score 0):

A Double value has up to 15 decimal digits of precision, you can refer to detail explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.double(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the decimal data type. It gives you an exact representation of numbers...for banking and stock markets I suppose. And you could reduce the mantissa to a certain length (perhaps 18).