# Double imprecise - C#

Tags: c#, double, poisson

The program is a Poisson Distribution, but when the number is very large, the factorial is imprecise and adds a few thousandths.

How could double make more precision?  Or is there a value with larger size?

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 15; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nx:{0} -------------------------- ", x);
    double num1 = Math.Pow(e, -lambda);
    double num2 = Math.Pow(lambda, x);

    double num = num1 * num2;

    fact = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    {
        fact = fact * i;
    }
    //Fact

    double fxres = 0;
    fxres = num / fact;
    Console.WriteLine("F(x): " + fxres);
    fx+= fxres;
    Console.WriteLine("\nSum: " + fx);

    number++;
```

Comment: I think decimal has more precision

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can C# store more precise data than doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473136/can-c-sharp-store-more-precise-data-than-doubles)

Comment: What are your requirements?   Would imprecision of a few millionths be OK?  How about a few billionths ?

Comment: If you were to measure the circumference of the earth using `double` your precision would be off by nano-meters. If that is not enough, use 128-bit decimal values.

Comment: `Math.Pow(e, -lambda)` never do this. Use `Math.Exp(-lambda)` instead. You use exp to get `e^x` in almost all programming languages

Comment: @micah - No, `decimal` does ***not*** have more precision. It has the same number of bytes as `double`, but it represents numbers differently, so has a different precision for different ranges. You need to be clear on what range you're talking about.

Comment: @Enigmativity I thought doubles had 8 bytes in C# while decimal has 16 bytes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: @micah - I could have sworn that they were the same. It appears I'm wrong. I must have gotten confused with `long`.